# Android: How to start a new fragment without destroying the state of the previous fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

How to replace Fragment_1 Fragment_2 with the ability to return back to the state and Fragment_1 (scroll, inputs, forms, other)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZNAo.gif)

If you use Activities, then you can use the method startActivityForResult. The work of this method perfectly shows the current task with fragments.

I do not want to save the values and then substitute them. We need that to Fragment_1 remained intact.

How to save the status of previous fragments at the opening of the new fragment_N and when you turn the screen using backstack?

Is there a ready library for the implementation of these tasks?

Comment: You can add new fragment and hide current one

Comment: coming back to hidden fragment from backstack will not loss the state of hidden fragment

Comment: @bhargav, 
Is it possible to show/hide fragment used for animation create/delete?

Comment: yes you can use show and hide fragments which are used for animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
t.hide(your_current_fragment);
t.add(container, new_fragment);
t.addToBackStack(TAG);
t.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.open_enter,R.anim.close_exit,R.anim.open_enter,R.anim.close_exit)
```

or

```
t.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
t.setTrans
t.commit();
```

replace `FragmentPagerAdapter`  with a `HorizontalScrollView` contains 2`FrameLayout` for `fragment`.You can freely change `fragment` in `FrameLayout`.

Comment: How can I change the fragment if it is created in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: In a ViewPager?Replace FragmentPagerAdapter with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and setoffsetlimit to count of your page!

Comment: Plz tell me what do you want to achevie.

Comment: I have viewpager. There are two fragments (Fragment A, Fragment B).
Fragment A can open up new fragments on top of, and the need to save the state and the ability to swipe.

Example:
https://swinechat.com/other/preview_2.jpg

Comment: Replace FragmentPagerAdapter  with a HorizontalScrollView contains 2Fragment for fragment .

Comment: No need to force a person to exercise moving for the finger to the end screen, using HorizontalScrollView

Comment: I need to use ViewPager + (hide/show fragment + add/remove fragment)

Comment: Why should you use a ViewPager?U can only need to Scroll to end when person's finger leave the screen.Try search for some thirparty horizontalScrollView.

Comment: In Fragment B will use the camera. HorizontalScrollView I think in this case will be less successful solution

Comment: System Camera is a Activity. HorizontalScrollview and ViewPager has no different

Comment: Thank you! I will think!

Comment: What to do when the coup of the screen? Fragment recreated.

Comment: I don't know.I always add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing fragment, You can add a new fragment and hide current one.

Something like this

```
FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
t.hide(your_current_fragment);
t.add(container, new_fragment);
t.addToBackStack(TAG);
t.commit();
```

It will not loss the state of hidden fragment

Comment: Is it possible to show/hide fragment used for animation create/delete?

Comment: yes you can use show and hide fragments which are used for animation

Comment: What to do when the coup of the screen? Fragment recreated.